# Chapter's name in the middle of the page without numbering page

Tags: vertical-alignment, chapters, fncychap

I want to have the name of each chapter (Only chapters, not chapter* , not TOC,..., jsut the chapters) in the middle of the page using the package Conny and without a page numbering in this page.

Here is my Work :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Chapter in Middle of page :
\let\oldDOCH\DOCH
\let\oldDOTI\DOTI
\let\oldDOTIS\DOTIS
\renewcommand\DOCH{\vspace{-50pt}\vfil\oldDOCH}
\renewcommand\DOTI [1]{\oldDOTI {#1}\vspace{-40pt}\clearpage}
\renewcommand\DOTIS[1]{\oldDOTIS{#1}\vspace{-40pt}\clearpage}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{1} 
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Introduction générale}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction générale}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Thématique}  
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

See below my result.

[image]

Comment: Unrelated, but you should use `[utf8]` input encoding  nowadays, not `[utf8x]` nor `latin1`.

Comment: Exactly, I just see the errors, I fixed it.

Comment: If I understand well  you want chapter titles to be on a page of its own?

Comment: Exactly, without the page numbering, and I want that only for \chapter not for \chapter* or TOC or something else. As you can see in my picture ( Chapitre 1 Thématique ) is on the middle of the page, as I want but the number of the page (5) figure in this page.

Comment: It can  easily be done with `titlesec`, but you have to emulate this style from `fncychap`.

Comment: How can I do this, can you help me ? I beggin with Latex.

Comment: How do the unnumbered chapters have to be?

Comment: Like TOC, in normal way using the Conny package with \chapter*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get this layout with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, french]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\titlerule[0.4pc]\vspace{3pt}\titlerule[1.2pt]\vspace{1ex}\filcenter\Huge}{\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~\thechapter\\\titlerule[1.2pt]}{-2ex}{\thispagestyle{empty}\uppercase}[\clearpage]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{40ex}{3ex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[display] {\titlerule[1.2pt]\filcenter\Huge}{}{-2ex}%
 {\thispagestyle{empty}\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter, numberless}{0pt}{-2.27ex}{12ex}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Introduction générale}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction générale}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Thématique}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I just tried this code and it worked, Thank you for your help, i'm learning day after day that's good :)

Comment: Just note one point: the starred `\titlespacing*`  command, contrary to the unstarred version, inhibits  first paragraph indent (which is  better according to some well-known French  typographers). Unfortunately `babel-french` makes it ineffective. There is a way to circumvent this problem, but I don't have time at the moment.  If you're interested, I can look at it later.

Comment: Oh I appreciate your help, but for now I can work with this, if I want something else I will mae you know, Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
\renewcommand\DOTI [1]{\oldDOTI {#1}\vspace{-40pt}\clearpage}
```

into

```
\renewcommand\DOTI [1]{\thispagestyle{empty}\oldDOTI {#1}\vspace{-40pt}\clearpage}
```

to remove the page number from pages with the chapter title.

Then remove the line

```
\renewcommand\DOTIS[1]{\oldDOTIS{#1}\vspace{-40pt}\clearpage}
```

to not vertically center `\chapter*` anymore.

Comment: It works, that's exactly what I want, thank you.